# HTML & CSS design techniques

Tags: html, css

I coded the attached file with a lot of position:absolute & other supplementary tags. I call them supplementary since I'm sure they weren't meant to be used in this way (shortcuts, hacks, situation-based etc.).

The problem is I'm completely new to front-end, so I'm not sure of how to go about this problem and produce authentic/correct code so no matter what the environment (resolution, platform etc.) the design element stays the way it is supposed to and doesn't lose its design with changes in the environment.

Lastly, I've heard about media queries and SASS/LASS mixins. Those I'm already looking into. Can someone please take a look and suggest what the proper **method**(not code) should be. Or whether this is how it's supposed to look and queries are the only way to handle changes (meaning my code is correct 8) ??)?

Screenshot of desired output/PSD

[image]

```html
<div class="body_caption" style="width:30%;">
  <img src="/mnt/n1/Office/<client name>/dev/res/png/Body/bracket-left.png" style="float:left;">
  <div style="clear:none;">
    <button style="background-color:#01acc8;padding:5px 15px;border-radius:12px;border:0;font-weight:bold;color:white;position:absolute;top:22%;left:5%;">INTRODUCING</button>
    <span style="position:absolute;left:5%;top:25%;">
 <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;color:#ffe658;">FRESH</span><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:70px;color:#ffffff;">&</span><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;color:#03acc9;">CLEAN</span>
    </span>
    <span style="color:#ffffff;position:absolute;top:120%;left:6%;">WE HELP CLEAN ALL YOUR NEEDS WITH OUR VARIOUS SKILLS AND RANGE OF SERVICES.</span>
    <img src="/mnt/n1/Office/<cleint name>/dev/res/png/Body/bracket-right.png" style="position:absolute;top:100%;left:95%;">
    <button style="position:absolute;top:210%;left:5%;width:52%;background:transparent;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;border-width:2pt;border-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;border-style:solid;padding:5px 40px;">FIND OUT MORE</button>
    <button style="position:absolute;top:210%;left:59%;width:52%;background:transparent;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;border-width:2pt;border-color:#ffffff;border-radius:5px;border-style:solid;padding:5px 40px;">GET A FREE QUOTE</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: check this link for css best practices http://www.tothenew.com/blog/10-best-practices-in-css/

Comment: TY for the reply... will do.

Comment: @vikasjadhav - just had a read... definitely something I need... cheers

Comment: @Gerard - ty for the formatting... just realised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <div class="body_caption" style="width:30%;position: relative;">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nsrpRz/111.jpg" style="background-size: cover;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;width: 100%;">
  <div style="clear:none;">
    <button style="background-color:#01acc8;padding:5px 15px;border-radius:12px;border:0;font-weight:bold;color:white;position:absolute;top:22%;left:5%;">INTRODUCING</button>
    <span style="position:absolute;left:5%;top:25%;">
 <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;color:#ffe658;">FRESH</span><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:70px;color:#ffffff;">&amp;</span><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:50px;color:#03acc9;">CLEAN</span>
    </span>
    <span style="color: #ffffff;position:absolute;top: 44%;left:6%;font-size: 21px;font-weight: 500;">WE HELP CLEAN ALL YOUR NEEDS WITH OUR VARIOUS SKILLS AND RANGE OF SERVICES.</span>
    <button style="position:absolute;top: 86%;left:5%;background:transparent;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 800;color:#ffffff;border-width: 2pt;border-color: #ffffff;border-radius:5px;border-style:solid;padding: 10px 60px;">FIND OUT MORE</button>
    <button style="background:transparent;border-width:2pt;position: absolute;top: 86%;left: 47%;font-size: 12px;font-weight: 800;color: #ffffff;border-color: #ffffff;border-radius: 5px;border-style: solid;padding: 9px 60px;">GET A FREE QUOTE</button>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/YJwVPR

Comment: I'm new to front-end, so I'm still struggling with why make the parent relative and the children absolute. Doesn't relative mean "relative to the parent" while absolute means complete on it's own. Or are those wordily definitions not applicable here? Because most of my dimensions were 100%+ which doesn't make sense... while yours are all within range (even though the output is not the same as required - not complaining :) )however values within range are a huge + all by themselves... and lastly, ty for your reply